# Creating indices for each group in Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in Spark with 2 columns, `group_id` and `value`, where `value` is a double. I would like to group the data based on the `group_id`, order each group by `value`, and then add a third column `index` that represents the position of `value` in the ordering of values for the group.

For example, considering the following input data:

```
+--------+-----+
|group_id|value|
+--------+-----+
|1       |1.3  |
|2       |0.8  |
|1       |3.4  |
|1       |-1.7 |
|2       |2.3  |
|2       |5.9  |
|1       |2.7  |
|1       |0.0  |
+--------+-----+
```

The output would then be something like

```
+--------+-----+-----+
|group_id|value|index|
+--------+-----+-----+
|1       |-1.7 |1    |
|1       |0.0  |2    |
|1       |1.3  |3    |
|1       |2.7  |4    |
|1       |3.4  |5    |
|2       |0.8  |1    |
|2       |2.3  |2    |
|2       |5.9  |3    |
+--------+-----+-----+
```

It is unimportant if the index is 0-based and whether the sort is ascending or descending.

As a follow-up, consider the case where there is a third column, `extra`, in the original data that takes on multiple values for some `(group_id, value)` combinations. An example is:

```
+--------+-----+-----+
|group_id|value|extra|
+--------+-----+-----+
|1       |1.3  |1    |
|1       |1.3  |2    |
|2       |0.8  |1    |
|1       |3.4  |1    |
|1       |3.4  |2    |
|1       |3.4  |3    |
|1       |-1.7 |1    |
|2       |2.3  |1    |
|2       |5.9  |1    |
|1       |2.7  |1    |
|1       |0.0  |1    |
+--------+-----+-----+
```

Is there a way to add an `index` column such that the `extra` column is not considered but still kept? The output in this case would be

```
+--------+-----+-----+-----+
|group_id|value|extra|index|
+--------+-----+-----+-----+
|1       |-1.7 |1    |1    |
|1       |0.0  |1    |2    |
|1       |1.3  |1    |3    |
|1       |1.3  |2    |3    |
|1       |2.7  |1    |4    |
|1       |3.4  |1    |5    |
|1       |3.4  |2    |5    |
|1       |3.4  |3    |5    |
|2       |0.8  |1    |1    |
|2       |2.3  |1    |2    |
|2       |5.9  |1    |3    |
+--------+-----+-----+-----+
```

I know that it is possible to do this by duplicating the data, dropping the `extra` column

1. Duplicating the data
2. Dropping the `extra` column
3. Performing a  `distinct` operation, which would result in data in the original example
4. Compute the `index` column using the original solution
5. Join the result with the data from the second example

However, this would involve a lot of extra computation and overhead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Window` functions to create a rank column based on `value`, partitioned by `group_id`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, dense_rank
# Define window
window = Window.partitionBy(df['group_id']).orderBy(df['value'])
# Create column
df.select('*', rank().over(window).alias('index')).show()
+--------+-----+-----+
|group_id|value|index|
+--------+-----+-----+
|       1| -1.7|    1|
|       1|  0.0|    2|
|       1|  1.3|    3|
|       1|  2.7|    4|
|       1|  3.4|    5|
|       2|  0.8|    1|
|       2|  2.3|    2|
|       2|  5.9|    3|
+--------+-----+-----+
```

Because, you first select `'*'`, you keep all other variables using the above code as well. However, your second example shows that you are looking for the function `dense_rank()`, which gives as a rank column with no gaps:

```py
df.select('*', dense_rank().over(window).alias('index'))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I've added an expanded example I was hoping you could look at.

Comment: see edit, you are probably looking for `dense_rank()`.